# Definition of separated and complete for topologically free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, modules

let $M$ be a a left module over the algebra of formal power series, $K=\mathbb{C}[[h]]$. Consider the family $(h^nM)_{n>0}$ of submodules and let $M_n = \frac{M}{h^nM}$. Consider the family of canonical $K$-linear projections, $$p_n: M_n \rightarrow M_{n-1}$$

They form an inverse system of $K$-modules, and we may consider the inverse limit $\tilde{M}$ which has a natural structure as a $K$-module. The inverse limit $\tilde{M}$ has a natural topology, the inverse limit topology, in which the family of submodules $(h^n\tilde{M})_n$ is a family of open neighborhoods. The module $\tilde{M}$ is called the h-adic completion of $M$.

The projections $i_n: M \rightarrow M_n$ induce a unique $K$-linear map $i: M \rightarrow \tilde{M}$ such that $\pi_n \circ i = i_n$ for all $n$. The kernel of $i$ is given by: $$Ker(i) = \bigcap_{n>0}h^nM$$

A $K$-module $M$ is separated if $\bigcap_{n>0}h^nM={0}$ and is called complete if the map $i$ is surjective.

Can somebody show me why these definitions of separated and complete are in this case equivalent to the definitions of complete and separated that a person would learn in a first semester point-set topology class? Thanks!

Comment: What are the definitions of "separated" and "complete" used in a first semester point-set topology class?  The term "Hausdorff" is used, and "complete" is used for metric spaces but not for general topological spaces (uniform spaces are not typically covered in a first course on topology).

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. Complete as in cauchy sequences all converge to an element and separated as in has multiple disjoint components that are both open and closed

Comment: Really I'm just trying to understand why they chose these terms at all, haha

Comment: Have you ever worked with an example of an inverse limit, such as the $p$-adic integers $\mathbf Z_p$?  If so, do you understand why $\mathbf Z_p$ is complete as a metric space, the mapping $\mathbf Z_p \to \varprojlim \mathbf Z_p/p^n\mathbf Z_p$ is surjective, and the mapping $\mathbf Z \to \varprojlim \mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$ is not surjective?

Comment: I have not, I'll do some reading though, Thanks for the reference!